# Assignment of Subscripts in Einstein Summation Notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to understand the following conversion from vector form into Einstein summation notation, found on P2 of [http://www.stanford.edu/~vkl/research/notes/index_not.pdf](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Evkl/research/notes/index_not.pdf) which states:

> Show $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla\mathbf{v} = \nabla\left(\frac{|\mathbf{v}|^2}{2}\right)+(\color{brown}{\nabla \times \mathbf{v})} \times \mathbf{v}$
>
> Proof: $v_a \partial_a v_b = \partial_b\left(\frac{v_av_a}{2} \right) + \epsilon_{bac}\color{brown}{(\epsilon_{adf}\partial_dv_f)}v_c \tag{*}$ (Rest of proof omitted here)

$\Large{\text{Question #1.}}$How did they get the LHS of (*)? I don't think my course covers the gradient of a vector, so I don't know how to convert it into Einstein notation. Or is it supposed to be $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}$?

$\Large{\text{Question #2.}} $ The solution seems to be working with the $b$th component of $ \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla\mathbf{v}$, but it doesn't say so. Because $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = \epsilon_{acb}u_av_j\color{red}{\mathbf{\hat{e_b}}}$,
is the solution missing  $\color{red}{\mathbf{\hat{e_b}}}$ on the RHS:  $$\partial_b\left(\frac{v_av_a}{2} \right) + \underbrace{\epsilon_{acb}}_{\Large{= \epsilon_{bac}}}\color{brown}{(\epsilon_{adf}\partial_dv_f)}v_c\color{red}{\mathbf{\hat{e_b}} }?$$

---

Here are two supplementary questions in response to tom's answer:

$\Large{\text{Question #1.1.}} $ How did you realise that $\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla\mathbf{v}$ should've been written as $(\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v}$?

$\Large{\text{Question #2.1.}}$ I don't understand your answer. $((\color{brown}{\nabla \times \mathbf{v})} \times \mathbf{v})$is a vector so why does the given solution not convert this to $\epsilon_{acb}\color{brown}{(\epsilon_{adf}\partial_dv_f)}v_c\color{red}{\mathbf{\hat{e_b}} }$?

---

Here are two supplementary questions in response to Muphrid's answer:

$\Large{\text{Question #1.2.}} $ What would be the "order of operations" which you mentioned in your answer?

$\Large{\text{Question #2.2.}}$ Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "...it would otherwise appear as the same basis vector in each term." Could you please clarify?

---

Here are two supplementary questions in response to Muphrid's 2nd answer:

$\Large{\text{Question #2.3.}}$ Could you please explain how a free index ($\color{red}{b}$ here) means that we are looking at the component of this free index ($\color{red}{b}$th component here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) It's $(v \cdot \nabla) v$, the directional derivative.  This is a common notation for it (dropping the brackets) because the gradient of a vector field doesn't fall under the scope of vector calculus--there is nothing else it could be.  You could also consider it an order of operations sort of thing, if you like.

(2) No, $\hat e_b$ is not missing, or rather, if it is missing, it is "missing" from every term.  The basis vector has been dropped from both sides for convenience.  You can verify that $b$ is the only free index on both sides, and it would otherwise appear as the same basis vector in each term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. Could you please look at two supplementary questions (#2.1 and #2.2) in response to your answer in my original post?

Comment: 1.2) Merely that the dot product has higher precedence than the derivative acting on the object to its right. I don't think there's a formal set of conventions here in vector calculus--generally, brackets are preferred. The only reason those brackets are dropped here is, again, because the gradient of a vector field is not defined in vector calculus. (2.2) I mean *every term* has $\hat e_b$, and every term has had it canceled.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Could you please look at another supplementary question (#2.3) added to my original post?

Comment: I don't feel like I have much of an answer to that question other than "that simply is what it means."  Write out a vector by itself: $v = v_b \hat e_b$.  Because the "free index" is always matched up with a basis vector with the same label, it's redundant information to have the basis vector there too, so it's almost always dropped (this also neatly avoids the question of what *two* free indices mean, and how two basis vectors can be present in an expression like that--that question is also interesting!).

Answer (score 1):

Q1:

Well $v\cdot \nabla v$ should be writen in form $(v \cdot \nabla) v$.

Nabla is $$\nabla = (\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z).$$ So

$$v\cdot \nabla = v_x\partial_x+v_y\partial_y+v_z\partial_z$$

Of course you can define gradient of vector valued function see [Jacobi matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

Q2:

Well no it is not. If by $\hat{e}_b$ you mean b-th basis vector.

$\partial_b\left(\frac{v_av_a}{2} \right)$ is scalar so 
$\epsilon_{bac}{(\epsilon_{adf}\partial_dv_f)}v_c $ has to be scalar too

Q1.1: Don't know what to say, but may I ask what is your definition of $\textbf{v} \cdot \nabla \textbf{v}$ ?

For me it is $\textbf{v} \cdot \nabla \textbf{v} =  (v_x\partial_x+v_y\partial_y+v_z\partial_z)\textbf{v}$ so there is not much to talk about.

Q2.1:
Yes you are right that $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = \epsilon_{abc}u_av_b\mathbf{\hat{e}_c}$ the same is with $\mathbf{v} = v_a \mathbf{\hat{e}_a}$ and $\nabla = \mathbf{\hat{e}_a} \partial_a $.

So  $\nabla\left(\frac{|\mathbf{v}|^2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\hat{e}_a}\partial_a (v_bv_b)$ and $(\nabla \times \mathbf{v}) \times \mathbf{v} = \epsilon_{abc} (\epsilon_{bef} \partial_e v_f) v_c \mathbf{\hat{e}_c}$.

For more info on term $v\cdot \nabla v$ see [Convective acceleration in Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Convective_acceleration)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please look at two supplementary questions in response to your answer, with which I've updated my original post?

Comment: Edited. I had mistake in original answer which should be fixed now.